# Sieve of Eratosthenes - Implementation returning some non-prime values?

Tags: java, math, primes, sieve

I implemented the Sieve of Eratosthenes in Java, from pseudocode:

```
public static void sieveofEratosthenes(int n) {
    boolean numArray[];

    numArray = new boolean[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        numArray[i] = true;

    int a = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt((double)n); i++) {
        if(numArray[i])  {
            for(int j = (int)Math.pow(i, 2); j < n; a++) {
                numArray[j] = false;
                j += (a * i);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if(numArray[i])
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The output it gives me, when i is 15:

```
2
3
5
7
8
11
12
13
14
```

Why are some of these values incorrect? I believe my error is in how I define and use the bool array. Thanks!

Comment: What do you think your inner loop (with index `j`) is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        for(int j = (int)Math.pow(i, 2); j < n; a++) {
            numArray[j] = false;
            j += (a * i);
        }
```

should read

```
        for(int j = (int)Math.pow(i, 2); j < n; j+=i) {
            numArray[j] = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

How SoE works is that it takes each number and "deletes" all numbers following it that are divisible by it. So basically each number **x + k*x** where **k > 0**. This can be done by simply adding **x** to the initial **x^2** and then adding iteratively **x** to it. Here:

```
for(int j = (int)Math.pow(i, 2); j < n; a++) {
    numArray[j] = false;
    j += (a * i);
}
```

You are not adding **x** but **a*x**, so you will skip some numbers as **a** is being incremented (so you will remove 4,6,10,16 etc, see the pattern? it adds 2,4,6 etc to the initial value) so you should stick with:

```
for(int j = (int)Math.pow(i, 2); j < n; j+=i) {
    numArray[j] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at line

```
 j += (a * i);
```

In loop, this statement gradually multiplies the j by a*i and **add** it with j.So replace above line with,

```
 j = (a * i);
```

It will work.
And yes,initialize

```
a=2
```

because we don't want numarray[0] or numarray[1] to initialize or use.
Do comment if any query. Thanks

Comment: Also, `a` must be reinitialized inside the `for (int i...)` loop.  Try and see what happens if you forget to do this.

Comment: yes, it would initialized by `2` after `for(int j...)` and inside `for(int i....)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly address your question, but since it's already been answered, I don't see any point in repeating it.  Looking at your code, though, I suggest using integer multiplication instead of `Math.pow` and `Math.sqrt` to get slightly better performance such as:

```
for(int i = 2; i*i < n; i++) {
    if(numArray[i])  {
        for(int j = i*i; j < n; j += i) {
            numArray[j] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Admittedly these calls will only be made once per iteration of the outer loop, so the improvement may not be very dramatic.  But, calling `Math.pow` and `Math.sqrt` are likely to be much more compute intensive than a single integer multiplication.  Also, if Java performs sufficiently sophisticated optimization, `i*i` may only get computed once and used in both places saving even more compute cycles.  There's also no risk of integer overrunning in this case since `i*i` is bounded above by the integer `n`.